# python crashes after running tensorflow with 3d convnet

Tags: python, memory, tensorflow, conv-neural-network

I'm running a tensorflow 3d convnet on medical image data and the python program crashes after it runs for about 50 minutes on cpu. The prompt does not produce any errors - it just crashes without any message.
I saw a similar question in [Tensorflow crashes when using sess.run()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37504470/tensorflow-crashes-when-using-sess-run)
But for my case, I am running this network on small batches, so I'm not sure if my computer is really running out of memory.(RAM: 32GB)

I would greatly appreciate any suggestions :)

Comment: How do you know it crashes, if it doesn't give you any message?

Comment: @jasekp The computer displays "python program has stopped working" And then the program returns nothing and ends right there.

Comment: Did you monitor the memory usage?

Comment: @Alex I tried monitoring as you said, and the cpu usage for python happened to go over 100%.

Comment: That doesn't necessarily mean anything since your cpu can have multiple cores. Was there memory pressure before the crash?

Comment: could you please share the code and some mount of data so that I can have a test on the model?